# Get ImageUniqueID in .tiff images

Tags: c#, .net, image, metadata

With the following Code-Snippet I get the UniqueImageId of an .jpg image. But the same code doesn't work for .tiff files. Anyone has an idea? Thx

```
Image myImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\path\to\picture.tiff");
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
PropertyItem pi = myImage.GetPropertyItem(42016);   // EXIF-Code -> UniqueImageID
string uniqueImageId = encoding.GetString(pi.Value, 0, 32);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

- Install this NuGet-Package: http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/ https://www.nuget.org/packages/BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET/
- Code example:

```cs
string uniqueImageId;
Tiff mytiff = Tiff.Open(absolutePath, "r");
FieldValue[] exifIFDTag = mytiff.GetField(TiffTag.EXIFIFD);
int exifIFDOffset = exifIFDTag[0].ToInt();
mytiff.ReadEXIFDirectory(exifIFDOffset);
FieldValue[] value = mytiff.GetField(TiffTag.EXIF_IMAGEUNIQUEID);
if (value != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        uniqueImageId = value[i].ToString();
    }

}
mytiff.Close();
```